# Delete payment step from checkout and connect to bank

Tags: checkout, payment

In my site because I'm using one bank for payment I want to delete payment step from checkout and when customer clicks the continue button in shipping method, review will show to customer and also the payment step done in backend. So after click order button in review step, customer will connect to bank for payment.

Also I want to do this without changing the core files because of update magento in future. But I don't know how can do this?

Thanks for help.

**EDIT:**

My question is different, now I have a problem that I now remove payment step but I want when I click the order button in review step it's connect to bank for payment but now it doesn't connect and after click order button in review step it shows me this page: `http://example.com/checkout/onepage/success/`

These are the files that I **add** to my site.

**Excellence:**

**app\code\local\Excellence**

1- app\code\local\Excellence\Remove\Block\Onepage.php

2- app\code\local\Excellence\Remove\controllers\OnepageController

3- app\code\local\Excellence\Remove\etc\config.xml

4- app\code\local\Excellence\Remove\Helper\Data.php

5- app\code\local\Excellence\Remove\Model\Method\Free.php

**remove.xml:**

**app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\layout\remove.xml**

**remove:**

**app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\template\remove**

1- app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\template\remove\checkout\onepage\review\info.phtml

2- app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\template\remove\checkout\onepage\progress.phtml

3- app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\template\remove\checkout\onepage\shipping_method.phtml

4- app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\template\remove\checkout\onepage.phtml

**Excellence_Remove.xml:**

**app\etc\modules\Excellence_Remove.xml**

**removecheckout.js:**

**skin\frontend\default\my-theme\js\removecheckout.js**

In which of these files I should make changes that with click order button in review button page connect to bank for payment?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: I see that but because I'm new in magento I can't understand his answer and which files should be change. can you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: If you have another question, you should open another one. Beside this, you should checkout the Mage_Paypal module. it is exactly doing what you want.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: Thanks for mention, I add bank module in Excellence_Remove.xml but nothing change!

Answer (score 0):

try adding this file to your theme:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\review\button.phtml
```

This is for the "place order" button, in this file you can assign another function to onClick or change the onSave() function.

Comment: I copy `button.phtml` from address that you said and paste it to  `app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\template\remove\checkout\onepage\review` that I create in my theme but it doesn't work!

Comment: Which of those files that I add in my theme should I add button.phtml in it? Because I think without adding this file in another file it doesn't work like right now that it doesn't work!

Comment: Then you might have to add it in remove.xml file.

Comment: I add it but nothing change.

Comment: Ok, so the button is not showing or if you click it nothing happens?

Comment: I have just the order button and when I click the button nothing happen.